# Problems with 2 ContextMenus

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have 2 ContextMenus, and second of it is called from the first.

Handler for first (creating second):

```
    private void MenuItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mI = (MenuItem)sender;

        if (mI.Header.ToString() == "England")
        {
            cM.Items.Clear();
            cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Barclays PL" });
            cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Championship" });
            cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "League 1" });
            cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "League 2" });
            cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Conference" });
            cM.Tap += MenuItem_Tap1;
            //if (cM.Parent == null)
            //{
                cM.IsOpen = true;
            //}
        }
    }
```

Handler for second:

```
        private void MenuItem_Tap1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mI1 = (MenuItem)sender;
        if (mI.Header.ToString() == "Barclays PL")
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/pEng.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

But there is System.InvalidCastException in second handler (MenuItem mI1 = (MenuItem)sender).

Please, help me, what's wrong?

Comment: What's the type of sender? (Hover over it and look at the type)

Comment: ContextMenu. And in first case all right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attaching the `MenuItem_Tap1` event handler to the `ContextMenu`'s `Tap` event instead of each `MenuItem`'s `Tap` event. Try this:

```
cM.Items.Clear();
cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Barclays PL" });
cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Championship" });
cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "League 1" });
cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "League 2" });
cM.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Header = "Conference" });

foreach( var item in cM.Items ) {
  ((MenuItem)item).Tap += MenuItem_Tap1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching your `Click` event to the `ContextMenu` and from the code and your comment, it's apparent you want to attach it to the `MenuItem`.